# Contact form actually does not create submit button? How can I fix this?

Tags: html

```
<div align="center">
    <fieldset>
        <form action="contact_submit.php" method="post">
            <i>Questions or comments? Would like to see new things on the site? Email any suggestions or concerns to the site administrator and you'll get a reply as soon as possible!</i><br/>
            <br/>
            Your Name
            <input type="text" name="cf_name">
            <br/>
            Your Email Address
            <input type="text" name="cf_email">
            <br/>
            Message
            <textarea name="cf_message">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <br/>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            <br/>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Not sure how to fix? would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: What is you question? What is your post?

Comment: you might start with closing tags `</form></fieldset></div>`

Comment: In fact, close all other tags as well! eg `<input type="..." />

Comment: @Veger Not needed if it's HTML5

Answer (score 4):

You have not closed the textarea tag

```
<textarea name="cf_message"></textarea>
```

It's probably as simple as that!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close your `<textarea>`

```
<textarea name="cf_message"></textarea>
----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```